# How to keep properties values in session scope?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I am using spring. i have an externalized properties file. i am loading it as below.

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="file:///C:/some.properties"/>
```

Now how can i keep properties in session as key-value pair ?

i tried writing a listener which extends ServletContextListener.

```
public class Sample implements ServletContextListener {
@Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
//here i tried to get the values of properties file as below.
InputStream stream = event.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("C:\\some.properties");
//But here stream is coming as null


}

}
```

Am i missing anything here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`SetvletContext`'s `contextInitlalized()` is called when the servlet context is initialized when the application loads successfully,

If you want to store it properties file in application context you can put it in

```
 event.getServletContext().setAttribute("global_properties", propertiesInstance);
```

If you want it on per session, then you need to hook it into [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html)'s  [`sessionCreated()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionCreated%28javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent%29) method

So put the data that is frequently used and that is shared across the application in `applicationscope` and the data that is limited to a session but frequently used put it in `session`

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. is contextInitlalized() called after loading the externalized properties file? Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome (if I answered your question really then you can upvote/mark the answer as accepted :) )

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest use PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer which communicates with a ServletContextListner. This class PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer has one method call processProperties in which you could get the map of all the properties.

```
 @Override
  protected void processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactoryToProcess,
  Properties props) throws BeansException {
  super.processProperties(beanFactoryToProcess, props);
  resolvedProps = new HashMap<String, String>();
  for (Object key : props.keySet()) {
      String keyStr = key.toString();

      resolvedProps.put(keyStr, parseStringValue(props.getProperty(keyStr), props,
              new HashSet()));
  }
}
```

And in the listner contextInitialized() you could do like:

```
ServletContext servletContext = sce.getServletContext();
  WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils
          .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
  ExposablePropertyPlaceHolder configurer =(ExposablePropertyPlaceHolder)context.getBean(propertiesBeanName);
  sce.getServletContext().setAttribute(contextProperty, configurer.getResolvedProps());
```

where ExposablePropertyPlaceHolder is the class which extends PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer.